# Can a developer change their product name on Steamworks?

Tags: steam

I recently got access to Steamworks and paid the product submission fee. Now I am able to create an app on Steam.

The app I'm working on is still untitled, but I want to start playing around with the Steamworks functionality.

Unfortunately, when I try to create a new app, Steamworks asks me for my product name. I am not sure if I will be able to change this later, so I am hesitant to proceed.

So my question is: **If I use a tentative name for my product on Steamworks, will I be able to change it later?**

I tried googling around, but couldn't find anything. There is too much noise from questions about changing one's username, etc.

Comment: Shouldn't you ask steam support this question?

Comment: Nothing about this seems off-topic to me.

Comment: Check out the Steamworks documentation, you're probably specifically looking for the Store Page edits: https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/store/editing

Comment: You should be asking on the Steamworks developer forum and you'll likely get a faster response: http://steamcommunity.com/groups/steamworks/discussions/0/ and I'm not sure if any responses you get would be allowed to be forwarded depending on what you signed

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Steamworks does allow you to change your product name.

If you want to change your product name, you need to make the change in three places. Each place is accessible from the app's landing page.

> 1. Edit Store Page > Basic Info > under "Game Name" (see [here](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/store/editing))
> 2. Store packages, pricing, & release dates > click package title > "Edit Package Name" on the right side of this page
> 3. Edit Steamworks Settings > Application  > under "Application Name and Type"

Answer (score 24):

**Yes**, you can change your product name. Several games that I own have changed names over the years. Some examples include:

- **Arma 2: Operation Arrowhead Beta (Obsolete)**. Previously called **Arma 2: Operation Arrowhead Beta**.
- **Serious Sam Fusion 2017 (beta)**. Previously called **Serious Sam Fusion**.
- **Skyrim Script Extender (SKSE)**. Previously called **SKSE**.

Comment: Retro Pixel Castles is now Rise to Ruins

Comment: Sequence is now Before the Echo. Someone had a valid copyright claim against the name and both parties found it easier to just have the dev change the game name after launch.

Comment: The only true Battlefront 2 is now (saddeningly) Battlefront 2 (Classic, 2005)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I choose to believe that they named it (Classic, 2005) because this latest one will eventually be (Classic, 2017) and they'll make a decent remake sometime in the future.